# Expand children by EE Addin Dll instead of autoexp.dat 's [Visualizer] section - children keyword

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Anyone aware if it is possible to create MS Visual Studio Debugger visualizer of expanding data in an Expression Evaluator (EE) Addin dll? Meaning to do in you Addin dll same as autoexp.dat's  [Visualizer] section does. In particular "children" expanding.